# HTAccess Rewrite: 301 Redirect Index but not Subdomain

Tags: git, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I'm creating an online community and I'm trying to set up a development server.

Currently, I'm using GIT as my repository.  I have both mysite.com and mysite.net; the .com being the primary site.

**My Goal:**

- If a user goes to www.mysite.net they
  should be 301 redirected to
  www.mysite.com.
- If a user goes to dev.mysite.net they should be asked for a password
  and then taken to the testbed.. (on mysite.net/)

Can this be done through some crafty htaccess rewrites?

**EDIT:**

```
# Here is what I have so Far
RewriteEngine on

#
## Redirect normal users to mysite.com
#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#
## Redirect dev.mysite.net to root directory of mysite.net/
#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev.mysite\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.net/$1 [R=301,L]


# REQUIRE Password for Dev Server
AuthUserFile /home/myaccount/public_html/mysite.net/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Development Server"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first goal is simply:

```
# redirect to primary
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Remove the www in the `RewriteRule` if you don't want to prefix.

Please comment back with more information regarding the second goal. I don't understand the testbed part.

Comment: Okay, good that will redirect the user from www.mysite.net/ to www.mysite.com/.  

Now for administrators I want to be able to visit www.dev.mysite.net/ and be asked for a password.  This will then take the admin to the root of mysite.net and Not redirect them to mysite.com.

Comment: Is the password protection by HTTP BASIC AUTH or custom?

Comment: If your .net site is under a separate directory structure in which you can place an .htaccess with HTTP BASIC AUTH, then just copy the above rule and change `(www\.)` to `dev.` and the use the .net address. This will then redirect dev.mysite.net to just the www.mysite.net.

Comment: Getting closer, the redirections work now.  The only problem is that users going to mysite.net/ are still asked for a password before redirecting them to mysite.com.  See my edited post above.  Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry, `(www\.)?` to `dev.`. Note the `?`. Also, I don't think you can share the same .htaccess. That's why I said *if* you have a *separate* directory structure. As it is now, it will require authentication for any of your sites.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the ? above.  I wasn't clear on what you meant by separate directory structures: I assumed you meant between the .net and .com (which are completely separate).  If you mean having a subfolder specifically for dev.mysite.net/ then they are the same.

Comment: I am still unclear on the setup, but you need to put the `AuthType` lines in your .htaccess file for the .net site, provided one exists. That should have it.